# Passing data between PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

The overall idea is drawing a graph of somebody's scores in a div. I've got a button which when clicked runs the graph drawing function. I also have another function which retrieves data from my database using a switch statement as the function is shared with the other buttons.

My data retrieval function:

```
var getdata = function(button_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../scripts/getdata.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {id: button_id},
        success: function(result){
            $("#profilebox").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

Runs getdata.php and returns values into a blank div.

getdata.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$switchcase = $_POST['id'];
$email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
//connect to database here
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
switch ($switchcase) {
    case "profile_home":
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['username'] . "'s Profile<br><br>";
        echo "Name: " . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . "<br><br>";
        echo "Things I like:<br>";
        echo $row['like'] . "<br><br>";
        echo "Things I dislike:<br>";
        echo $row['dislike'] . "<br><br>";
        echo "Other Sports:<br>";
        echo $row['sports'];
    };
        break;
    case "profile_scores":
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row['correct'];
        $row['incorrect'];
    };
        break;
    case "profile_merits":
        //CODE GOES HERE;
        break;
    case "profile_help":
        //CODE GOES HERE;
        break;
    case "profile_edit":
        //CODE GOES HERE;
        break;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Receives POSTed div id (profile_scores), gets data from database, switches to second case. Now here is where the problem is, I'm not sure how to pass the

```
        $row['correct'];
        $row['incorrect'];
```

values back to the original page and get them to show up in the graph where

```
/* correct value */
```

and

```
/* incorrect value */
```

are.

Graph drawing function:

```
function drawVisualization() {

    getdata("profile_scores");

    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['', 'Correct', 'Incorrect'],
        ['Scores',  /* correct value */, /* incorrect value */],
    ]);

    var options = {
            'title': 'Total Scores Overall',
            'width': 600,
            'height': 400,
            'hAxis': {title: ''},
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
    };
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('profilebox')).
    draw(data, options);
};
```

This function is what is ran when the user clicks the button so it calls the getdata function and then draws the graphusing the values received from getdata.php.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Would you like to state what you want to do in easy and few words?

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for

Comment: Does the 'var phparray', 'var correct' and 'var incorrect' have to go in the success function in the ajax block?

Comment: take a look at my answer I have updated. Check it if you have any question

Comment: I keep getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: correct is not defined' in the console. I'm pretty new to this type of web work :/

Comment: see updated answer of mine and let me know what you get now

Comment: ["1","Jake","Mansell","Tester","//a password","test@email.com","Sports, Music, Partying","Working","Roller Derby, Running","100","10","0","0"]
["1", "Jake", "Mansell", "Tester", "//a password", "test@email.com", "Sports, Music, Partying", "Working", "Roller Derby, Running", "100", "10", "0", "0"]

Comment: @Jack Mansell look this shows that your php is sending database result to Javascript correctly now you can access any value from your array with its key like to access email in javascript you can phparray[5] and Jack please Comment on my answer.

Comment: @Jack Mansell Look my answer update

Comment: Did you get what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally not sure what you are asking for but here is my guess.

If you want the **$result** fetched in **case 2** from database on your page. Then you can use JSON to pass PHP array to Javascript and then do the rest of the job. Like suppose this is the case no 2 of your switch statement

```
case "profile_scores":
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    echo json_encode($row);
    break;
}
```

And in your ajax response do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../scripts/getdata.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {id: button_id},
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
        var phparray = JSON.parse(result);
        var correct = phparray[12];   //<---This will return 100 
        var incorrect = phparray[13];  //<---This will return 10
        //I Dont know which one is your correct or incorrect column number but you can have an idea now
    }
});
```

This way you got your PHP array to javascript which was database result. Also I would like to suggest you to correct the Switch syntax. This won't make much difference but should be taken care so this is the correct syntax.

```
switch($switchcase)
{
   case "case1":
   {
       //Code to go
       break;
   }
   case "case2":
   {
       //Code to go
       break;
   }
   case "case3":
   {
       //Code to go
       break;
   }
}
```

Note that I have put **break;** command inside **Switch Case**

Comment: If you have any problem comment here not in your question

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much, this helped a lot. I was getting errors but I realized some of my functions could be combined so that it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code can encode the returning parameters in a (JSON-encoded) associative array. Then you can retrieve each of them separately via the keys from your ajax response and pass them around in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json.php to get json parsed string for javascript call.
Download link: [class.json.php](http://devpro.it/code/140.html)

Changes in Javascript:

```
   var getdata = function(button_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../scripts/getdata.php",
            dataType: "json", // html -> json
            data: {id: button_id},
            success: function(result){

                $("#profilebox").html(result.html);

                return result;
            }
        });
    };

    function drawVisualization() {

        var data = getdata("profile_scores");

        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['', 'Correct', 'Incorrect'],
            ['Scores',  data.correct, data.incorrect],
        ]);

        var options = {
                'title': 'Total Scores Overall',
                'width': 600,
                'height': 400,
                'hAxis': {title: ''},
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
        };
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('profilebox')).
        draw(data, options);
    };
```

Changes in getdata.php:

```
<?php
    // INCLUDE JSON
    // ----------------------------
    include_once("class.json.php");
    $json = new JSON();

    $coreJSON = array();
    // ----------------------------

    session_start();

    $switchcase = $_POST['id'];

    $email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];

    // call as result.html in javascript
    $coreJSON['html'] = ""; 
    // call as result.correct in javascript
    $coreJSON['correct'] = "";
    // call as result.incorrect in javascript
    $coreJSON['incorrect'] = "";

    //connect to database here
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    switch ($switchcase) {

        case "profile_home":  // <- CHANGES

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $coreJSON['html'].= <<<EOF
                    {$row['username']}'s Profile<br /><br />
                    Name: {$row['firstname']} {$row['lastname']}<br /><br />
                    Things I like:<br>
                    {$row['like']} <br /><br />
                    Things I dislike:<br />
                    {$row['dislike']}<br /><br />
                    Other Sports:<br />
                    {$row['sports']}
EOF;
            }
            /* Start the closing EOF at the beginning of the line, and delete all spaces and tabs after the semicolon. Next code must start in a new line.*/

            break;

        case "profile_scores":

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $coreJSON['correct'].= $row['correct']; // <- CHANGES
                $coreJSON['incorrect'].= $row['incorrect']; // <- CHANGES
            }

            break;
        case "profile_merits":
            //CODE GOES HERE;
            break;
        case "profile_help":
            //CODE GOES HERE;
            break;
        case "profile_edit":
            //CODE GOES HERE;
            break;
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    // CLOSING AND CONVERTING
    // ----------------------------
    $encodeJSON = $json->encode($coreJSON);

    header('Content-Type: text/json'); // text/plain is good to
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($encodeJSON));

    die($encodeJSON); 
    // ----------------------------
?>
```

I hope it helps a bit.